# точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке dll qt

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator

К сожалению имею уникальный случай, поскольку в всплывающим окне ошибки буквально следующие сообщение "точка входа в процедуру не найдена в библиотеке dll в test/test.exe".Ни название функции, не имя самой dll.
Я получил исходники и саму программу с библиотеками,программа запускается исходники собираются, но стоит мне перекинуть exe-шник с одной папки в другую вылетает это дурацкое окно с ошибкой. Собираю релизной версией. Мне как раз важно перенести только экзежник, поскольку есть не qt библиотека с лицензией и сама лицензия.

Comment: Перекидывайте exe вместе со всеми библиотеками.

Comment: Попробую, только вопрос, какова природа этой ошибки?

Comment: Очевидно присутствует зависимость от одной или нескольких dll, которые не находятся если exe в другой папке

Comment: Обычно он пишет, что не хватает какой нибудь dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt бесплатный или платный? Если бесплатный то он exe файл собирает в динамике как того требует опенсорсная лицензия. Что бы вот так просто exe копировать, его надо собрать в статике, при такой сборке qt пропишет все зависимые библы в исполняемый файл. В общем то в нете полно инструкций как собрать со статической линковкой и в бесплатной версии qt.